# Data frame no longer a data frame once element is removed

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple data frame as

```
myframe<-data.frame(c(NA, NA,NA, 1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9))
```

I remove the first element like so:

```
myframe<-myframe[-1,]
```

And when I do this:

```
is.data.frame(myframe)
```

The result I get is:

```
[1] FALSE
```

I can fix it by:

```
myframe<-data.frame(myframe[-1,])
```

but I thought that the data frame wouldn't stop being a data frame after removing elements

What's happening here? I've been coding all day and my brain is fried and I cannot figure this out. Please help.

My objective is to only remove the first n occurences of NAs in a data frame. If they occur somewhere in the middle, it doesn't matter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you only have one column, R automatically converts the result to a vector. If you want to preserve the data frame structure you can type

```
myframe[-1, , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: And from the documentation: drop: logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.

Comment: Thanks guys! All this time I never ran into this.. R, y u do dis!!!!